# Why use async without await in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have seen so many people defining async function without using await in it like this.

```js
async function authMiddleware(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.query.token
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET
    jwt.verify(token, secret)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: MESSAGES.TOKEN_EXPIRED })
  }
  return next()
}
```

I've attached this code just for an example. Please don't care the meaning of lines inside.

Is there any good point or use case of defining a function as async without any `await` in javascript?

Possibly: is it possible that he intended to inform the user that it returns promise?

Comment: Seems pretty strange. Only reason I could think of would be if they were planning on adding an asynchronous call in there shortly

Comment: no, it is stable code. is it possible that he intended to inform the user that it returns promise? @CertainPerformance

Comment: async will wrap the return in a Promise implicitly if it is not a Promise.

Comment: There's absolutely no point in that case, it just makes the code more difficult to use, not to mention confusing

Comment: @CertainPerformance Where is the difficulty of use? I assume it acts the same without async

Comment: It will require the consumer to consume the Promise, which requires either a `.then` or `await`, which may require further unnecessary restructuring of *its* consumers to deal with the asynchronousness.

Comment: @think-serious It will not work the same if you remove async, In your case it just wraps the next() in Promise.resolve(next()).

Comment: @CertainPerformance no need to use .then or await. the async function will return already resolved promise if there is no promise/await inside the function.

Comment: No, even if the async function doesn't await anything, consumers of that function will still get a Promise in return, and in order to consume it, they will have to use `.then` or `await`

Comment: A resolved promise is still a promise.

Comment: Looking at where and especially how `authMiddleware` is consumed in the source code would probably allow to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: most likely answer - async/await is the *new toy* - everyone wants to play with it before reading the instructions

Comment: @JaromandaX Not so clear with your comment. Would you make some detailed comment/answer to explain more for me?

Comment: in a nutshell ... the code is using `async` just because `async` exists, not for any other reason

Answer (score 5):

What ESLint says with its rule [require-await](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await).

> Asynchronous functions in JavaScript behave differently than other
>   functions in two important ways:
>
> - The return value is always a Promise.
> - You can use the await operator inside of them.
>
> The **primary reason** to use asynchronous functions is
>   typically to use the await operator, ...

What [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) says :

> **The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function** — a
>   function that returns an AsyncFunction object. Asynchronous functions
>   operate in a separate order than the rest of the code via the event
>   loop, returning an implicit Promise as its result. But the syntax and
>   structure of code using async functions looks like standard
>   synchronous functions.

It is clear that **async functions are not only made for await use**. Then, not having await in an async function is ok. But... what is the point ?

I believe it is to use a synchronous function like a Promise. The following example is from [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/async-await).

```
async function f() {
  return 1;
}

f().then(alert); // 1
```

Would be the same as:

```
async function f() {
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}

f().then(alert); // 1
```

> Is there any good point of defining a function as async without any
>   reason in javascript?

It may be used to make code more readable or easy to follow.

Results client-side will not be impacted.

Answer (score 1):

For you shown code, it does not make any sense, because it is - at least I assume - an express middleware and expressjs does not use the returned Promise of that middleware. And without an `await` in that `async` middleware the only thing that changes is that the middleware returns a `Promise`, and as expressjs does not use that returned Promise, so the `async` keyword here is pointless and can be even harmful, if the something in `authMiddleware` throws a not cached error.

And it does not make sense to use it `without any reason`. You can use `async` and `await` to convert an otherwise long-running synchronous process into smaller chunks so that other code can interleave,  as `await`/`async` allows you introduce some kind cooperative multitasking. But only adding `await`/`async` to a long-running task alone would not prevent you from blocking the event loop.

If you have a code like this:

```js
function testA() {
   for( let i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
      console.log('testA', i)
   }
}

function testB() {

   for( let i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
      console.log('testB', i)
   }
}

testA();
testB();

console.log('finished');
```

Then you could use `await` and `async` to allow other code to interleave, by changing it to.

```js
async function testA() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('testA', await i)
  }
}

async function testB() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('testB', await i)
  }
}

Promise.all([
  testA(),
  testB()
]).then(() => {
  console.log('finished');
})
```

Comment: This isn't my code, so I want to know the reason he used async without using await inside. And yes, the function is express middleware, but I don't think it matters

Comment: @think-serious It matters because it is relevant if the code execution the async function does anything with the returned `Promise`. The async function is executed immediately, it only pauses at an `await` and as no `await` is present, the only thing that happens is that a `Promise` is returned and expressjs does not do anything with the returned `Promise`. So for the given code, it does not make any sense to place `async` here.

Answer (score 0):

> Above written code is intended to returning an implicit Promise as its
>   result.

Like

```
async function firstFunction(a , b) {
   do some stuff here.....
}
function secondFunction(res){
 do some stuff here.....
}
async function thirdFunction(items){
 const data = await fetch('url here');
 const result = await data.json();
 do some stuff here........
}
```

> so Here is the deal....

firstFunction(2,3)
.**then**((resOfFirst) => secondFunction(resOfFirst))
.**then**((resOfSecond) => thirdFunction(resOfSecond))

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

For the example code provided, I guess the developer had intentions of making it asynchronous (not blocking event-loop) in the future but he didn't know an easy way to do so. The thing is `jwt.verify` doesn't provide a `Promise` based API, it accepts an optional third callback parameter in which case it will be executed asynchronously. Again **I guess** the developer wasn't confident about using callback API, or he has been religious about using `async/await` wherever possible.

A possible solution using `async/await`, could be to [promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) `jwt.verify` and `await` on that promisified function call:

```
const verifyJwtAsync = Bluebird.promisify(jwt.verify);

async function authMiddleware(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.query.token
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET
    await verifyJwtAsync(token, secret)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: MESSAGES.TOKEN_EXPIRED })
  }
  return next()
}
```

A simpler callback-based solution is as follows:

```
async function authMiddleware(req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.query.token
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function(err) {
       if (err) res.status(403).json({ message: MESSAGES.TOKEN_EXPIRED });
       else next();
    })
}
```