# Javascript: returns NaN with a function only using Math

Tags: javascript, math

I have a few async functions that only involve numbers.

```js
async function xp() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    return random;
}
```

This one returns a number. It has been checked with `typeof` and returns an integer for its value.

```js
async function lvl(xp) {
    let discriminant = Math.sqrt(10 * 10 - 4 * 10 * (-(xp - 40)));
    let n1 = (-10 + discriminant) / (2 * 10);
    let n2 = (-10 - discriminant) / (2 * 10);
    let n = n1 >= 0 ? Math.floor(n1) : Math.floor(n2);
    console.log('n', n, typeof n);
    return n;
}
```

This one, however, returns `n NaN number` in logs, where the parameter `xp` is the result of the previous function.

Here is where the two are combined:

```js
let newXp = await xp();
let total = check.data[0].xp + newXp;
console.log('total', total, typeof total);
let level = await lvl(total);
```

`total` returned `25` as type `number`.

How come this second function returns `NaN` when it's only using Math on a number parameter?

Comment: I just added a bit more detail on how I use the two together. @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `check.data[0].xp` has the value of an integer saved in a database.

Comment: Your `let discriminant = Math.sqrt(10 * 10 - 4 * 10 * (-(xp - 40)));` returns NaN. That's why. You cannot use negative numbers when using Math.sqrt :)

Comment: If `xp` is  say `25` the calculation for `10 * 10 - 4 * 10 * (-(xp - 40))` will be `-500`

Comment: Here's a similar (Java language) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461803/why-quadratic-equations-root-result-is-nan-java

Comment: Off topic, but you should only make a function `async` if it does an `await` call to at least one other `async` function, something like `... = await someFn()`. If you do not make any `await` calls in an `async function` then you are only making things more complicated then they need to be. This applies to both `xp()` and `lvl()`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59701690/1220550

Answer (score -1):

Negative numbers don't have square roots since a square is either positive or 0:

```js
const xp = 25; 

const calc = 10 * 10 - 4 * 10 * (-(xp - 40));  // -500
const discriminant = Math.sqrt(calc);          // NaN
```

So there is something wrong in the way you calculate the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).

---

PS; I'm not exactly sure why do you use `async` without `await`, in order to return a Promise? Also, use `const` (instead of `let`) where needed.

Comment: Although the negative discriminant might really be where the NaN is coming from, OP can't simply replace sqrt(something) with sqrt(abs(something)) because it changes what the equation means. Maybe it makes sense in the context of what OP is doing, but verifying that requires more information than what's available at this point.

Comment: @RobertDodier absolutely. Removed the pointless *"use Math.abs() to..."*.

Comment: Oh, is it not using await? I’m planning on using these within other asyncs which includes await.